# chmsee not opening php manual

Tags: 10.04, chm, chmsee

I have chmsee 1.0.7 installed on Ubuntu 10.04. It opens a small chm files (1Mb or 2Mb files) but when I try to open php manual chm file which weights about 10Mb it doesn't open it and doesn't show any error message.

Where is the problem? Has anybody met this problem ever?

Comment: Please runt it form the terminal and update your question with any error message that you might get when opening the file, also please detail "doesn't open it", does it show some message ?

Comment: I run it from terminal and when I open the small chm file it opens. But when I open php manual chm file it doesn't open and doesn't show any message. In the terminal also there is no any message.

Comment: A chm reader is reasonable.So ask your admin to install xchm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the google code htmlhelp link: http://code.google.com/p/htmlhelp/wiki/CHM

you can see all the viewers and some formats that happen to be in some chm and not others. That is why you can see in perfect condition some and not others.

This is just a seccion of the above link:

Format

Microsoft never released the format specification, but there are a few reverse engineered descriptions of the format:

- Unofficial CHM Specification
- Matthew Russotto's Microsoft's HTML Help format description

There are some tools which allow to read the contents of CHM files:

- CHMLIB
- libmspack — a library for Microsoft compression formats

Viewers

- Microsoft HTML Help Viewer
- xCHM — a CHM viewer for UNIX (Linux, BSD, Solaris), written by Razvan Cojocaru
- JouleData Solutions' CHM Viewer — a comercial 100% native Cocoa .chm file viewer for the Mac OS X platform
- GnoCHM — a CHM file viewer. It is designed to integrate nicely with Gnome.
- chmviewer
- ChmSee
- Chmox — a Mac OS X CHM viewer
- KchmViewer — a Qt/KDE based viewer of CHM files

Answer (score 1):

Use [**xchm**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xchm) [image: Install xchm] it works fine for me.

Comment: I haven't root access to Ubuntu. I am a simple user and therefore I have no privileges to do that. That's why i need to use only chmsee.

Comment: Maybe you can explain to your system admin(s) and ask them to install xchm or any another tool that works?